# "Flight recorder" for automobiles?

Tags: brakes, speedometer, gauges

As I sat in traffic court last week for a non-moving violation, many of the cases were clearly he said/she said issues.. particularly with stop sign violations.   I can easily see how this specific problem could be a source of abuse by both police and citizens.

Case in point - I stop at all stop signs.  I usually count to 2 before moving, but because of the location of the white line, It may look like I never really stopped to someone coming along the cross street.

Are there any court-admissible devices that will accurately (and affordably) record auto movement, and perhaps speed?

Comment: gis declared it OT as well.  I've managed to stike the imperfect balance between the two!

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/254152/senate_passes_bill_requiring_black_boxes_in_all_new_cars.html

Comment: @Nick - interesting, though I don't like the requirement part of this bill.

Comment: @a-coder - There's also this way: http://articles.businessinsider.com/2012-04-16/news/31348379_1_optical-illusion-sign-paper

Answer (score 2):

Considering that all cars after 96 I believe have OBD installed, it is possible to make a device that records your every move (I am actually making one [as we speak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/4573/602)). ODB may do this already (the car needs this info for other tasks).

However, this is not necessarily court approved and depending on the offense and the level of court it may not be admissible.