# How do I find the correct pins in a CAN-BUS connector?

Tags: motorcycle, bmw, obd-ii, computer, can-bus

This question might be too technical for this forum, but I'll give it a go. I have a 2012 BMW R1200R motorcycle with CAN-BUS. I'd like to make an Arduino interface to the connector on the bike, but I don't know the pin definitions...

Do anyone know the pin definitions or how to figure out what they are?

**UPDATE:**

```
Pin #.Wire color.Ohms with disconnected battery.Voltage with key off.Voltage with key on  
1     Green/Blue  3.2 ohms                       0 V                   12.25 V  
2     Red         2.2 KOhms                      12.9 V                12.32 V  
3     Brown       0.4 Ohms                       0 V                   0 V
4     Brown/Black 16 Ohms to 12.4 Ohms           ~0.003 V              11.2 V
```

Pin 2: *Two +12V lines probably means this is a battery pin?*

Pin 3: *Possible ground pin with two 0 volt pins?*

**Update 2:**

The [OBD Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics) shows that for these pins it must be one of three protocols: ISO 9141-2, [ISO 14230](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_14230) or [ISO 15765](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controller_Area_Network). I don't have all the chips needed to test 9141 or 14230, but I'll have them and another update within two weeks.

[image: R1200 Diagnostic Plug]

Comment: Have you asked over on advrider.com? There may be some GS eggheads that could help.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that it isn't a standardised pinout, so you'll have to find a BMW-specific pinout for it unfortunately...

Comment: mac - Thanks, I'll give them a shot.Nick - Yeah, I figure it's going to be harder than it should be. I was hoping to just bust out an O-scope and stumble upon the right one.

Comment: if you find anything out, be sure to post your own answer!

Comment: Update: So, I blew up my first board by just plugging it into some wires. I now have a new board and will test my code on my car's system which is well documented.

Comment: I"m interested if you ever achieved your goal.  You wouldn't happen to have an update would you?  I know this is 3+ years later but.....hoping you do.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the similar thing and stumbled on a page which describes the protocol for the 650gs. I haven't managed to try it out yet but it seems promising. http://www.f650gs.crossroadz.com.au/Diagnostics.html

Topic is discussed here as well: 
http://f650.com/forum/showthread.php?25550-Diagnostic-plug-pinout-does-anyone-have-it

Plese let my know how are you doing with your project. I have a similar arduino-gs-related thing in mind :)

Comment: A friend is borrowing my Arduino currently, but after scanning the diagnostics page you posted I did a quick search and I think I'll try [this][http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/millerrv/Ryan_Miller/Projects/Entries/2010/12/21_Arduino_OBD-II_Interface.html] site out